# Can the Operator Panel in 2.8+ be moved?

Tags: interface, customization

I'm not liking how far the new Operator Panel encroaches into the working area of the Viewport. Is there a way to move it?

[image]

The ability to truly minimize it now is a huge help. I'm just wondering if it can be repositioned too.

Comment: I can't overstate how much this gap is triggering my OCD :).

Comment: @JachymMichal I know what you mean.  ;-)  However, after posting this I realized the annoyance could be avoided by changing my workflow a little bit. I posted an answer explaining, in case you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have since realized that since I rely on shortcuts and don't use *any* of the buttons on the T panel, I can just collapse it (<kbd>T</kbd>) and save my Startup File that way.

Then the Operator panel slides over to the left corner and has a nice place where it can stay collapsed until I need to tweak params. Then I can click it to expand it and do that. It all works out.

Reference:

[image]

<sup>(Pretty obvious, actually. But as I've just jumped from 2.79 to 2.9 I'm still getting adjusted to the new UI.)</sup>

I'm still welcoming answers with regard to customizing the placement of the T Panel and Operator Panel in 2.8+, in case anyone else has something to add. Maybe a customization tip or trick that isn't so obvious?

Comment: ( you can also exploit the power of F9...)

Comment: If you switch to 2.79 input, you can use F6 to’swap’ tool bar to the opposite side next to the N panel which I do to use less travel for my tool selection. You can easily look up the current operator key map assignment as well or make your own too.

Comment: @CraigDJones Thanks, but I'm not sure what you mean by "swap" the toolbar. I couldn't find any info on that. Or do you just mean calling Adjust Last Operation as a floating overlay (which is now done by pressing F9)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 2.7X keymap temporarily and swap the toolbar to the opposite side by hovering and pressing 'F5'. I'll include a shot of the keymapping.
I prefer the tools on the right because as a right handed person, I like to keep my travel short from the right side of the screen. Default has me swinging my mouse back and forth across the screen too much.
[image]
[image]
[image]